# Disable gzip for a specific directory

Tags: nginx

For training purposes I would like to deactivate gzip for a specific directory. The following config doesn't do the trick. How can I deactivate it?

```
location /webperf/disabledgzip/ {
  gzip_disable "*";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
location /webperf/disabledgzip/ {
  gzip off;
}
```

As albal said, `gzip_disabled` has a different purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [gzip](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html#gzip) directive as in `gzip off;`

[gzip_disable](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html#gzip_disable) is for disabling gzipping of responses based on User-Agent.